# Not able to connect to jenkins from browser

Tags: jenkins

I have my jenkins running on a Virtual machine which hosted on a server.I am running it using java -jar jenkins.war. It is fully up and running but when I try to open it browser by public_ip_of_server:8080 it doesn't open up. Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which Virtual machine are you using? For virtual box you have to forward the ports you would like to access: https://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/ If it is an azure vm I would recommand using a template like: https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/azure-oss.jenkins?tab=Overview

Comment: yeah,you're right.